# Starting motor for 1 minute after every 2 hours

Tags: microcontroller

My requirement for hydroponic fodder trays, I wants to spray the water in every 2 hours for 1 minute. Can anybody tell me how I can achieve this in lowest budget as wanted to distribute this technic on large scale to farmers.

With the information I have, I need to purchase 
Option 1. 555 timer IC and Relay? And please suggest how? 
Option 2. Some sort of ready made controller like adriuno? And please suggest how?
Option 3. ???? ? And please suggest how?

Comment: This sounds like an under resourced product development programme to me; you say you have a "large scale" market but you are after free advice here - have you got a guy working on this or maybe someone who can give you advice over a period of a couple of hours going thru all the options. It's too broad a question and should be closed.

Comment: Andy, I mentioned it on large scale to help poor farmers in india (where farmers commit suicide, due to very less money problems) not for doing any business, for noble cause only. Even anybody can take this idea from here and help them not restricted to me. (If I get any solution would help other as well). Hope you understand.

Comment: I stand entirely by my original comments and your reply, to the casual reader could (on the face of it) appear to be a slur on my ethics. Back off dude and read my comment again when I say "It's too broad a question and should be closed".

Comment: I don't think you've really thought this through since, if they're so destitute that they're on the verge of committing suicide, then never mind the timer, how are they going to be able to afford the pump, the pipe, the sprinkler heads,  and all the rest of the paraphernalia needed to do hydroponic farming?

Comment: thanks for your comments, I don't wants go into deep discussion what farmers can afford or not. In india, 70% - 80% farmers has few animals ( 2 bulks, 1-1 cow or couple of goats). And my intention to increase the food quantity/quality so that they can afford more animals and increase their earning.. Thought of asking some talented guys like you here..(Costing I can thought of $30 pump + $10 pipe+sprinkler + electronic device-expected in range of $10 +  2X2 feet 7 trays $30 = Total $80) number of trays can be increased with increases number of animals with same setup. Help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to tell us 1) Is the power supply mains, battery or solar? 2) What are you switching - a pump or a valve? At what voltage and current / power? What water flow rate?

Comment: The obvious answer is a small micro, like PIC 10F200, driving a relay.  The relay then runs the pump.

Comment: Seven 2X2 foot trays is only 28 square feet, so what's wrong with watering the fodder every hour using a cheap watering can until you can afford better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use this system for agricultural applications you can go for the 89C51 micro controller you can use one of the port of microcontroller to control the motor. By inserting delay in the microcontroller assembly language program you can controll the motor as per your any timing requirements

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete circuit using a dual 556 timer chip to obtain a long duration delay with a secondary short delay.  (Note the circuit drawing shows 565, but its a 556).  To get the short delay time correct refer to the 555 or 556 data sheet (link at the bottom) and adjust the RC values as needed.

http://www.electroschematics.com/9082/long-duration-timer/

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined large scale. Let's assume you produce 1 million devices. You can get 8051 processors featured for motor control applications and 32kB flash for 25cents, so I assume the MCU you need is sub 0.10 USD. NE556 is probably around 0.05USD. I would go for MCU, as 0.05 USD is irrelevant against the price of the relay, and MCU is a much more flexible solution.

Comment: Jacen, my apologies actually I should have not mentioned "large scale" in the question which is causing confusion here. I am not owning any factory or producer. I am looking for smallest possible unit which can be expanded with the time or requirement.